# Rails link to remote site in a partial pop-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to render a link to an external site in a pop up from my site in Rails. What's the best way to go about doing that?

e.g. I want to have something like www.cnn.com show up in a pop-up partial when a link is clicked on my site.

Comment: What you need is javascript feature, Rails can't help in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make cross domain ajax calls to show inside a popup. So it won't be so easy as rendering a link. You can try using a iframe inside that popup.